# JSON: Error while Parsing

Tags: javascript, json

I've the following `JSON`(Valid) sting.

```
[["abc","{\"icon\":\"adjust\",\"prefix\":\"fa\",\"markerColor\":\"red\"}"],["xyz","{\"icon\":\"archive\",\"prefix\":\"fa\",\"markerColor\":\"green\"}"],["azs","{\"icon\":\"asterisk\",\"prefix\":\"fa\",\"markerColor\":\"darkred\"}"]]
```

it gives error when I try to Parse using the `JSON.parse` function
here is the code that I'm using for parsing.

```
JSON.parse('[["abc","{\"icon\":\"adjust\",\"prefix\":\"fa\",\"markerColor\":\"red\"}"],["xyz","{\"icon\":\"archive\",\"prefix\":\"fa\",\"markerColor\":\"green\"}"],["azs","{\"icon\":\"asterisk\",\"prefix\":\"fa\",\"markerColor\":\"darkred\"}"]]');
```

and it gives an error in console `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token i`

here is the Correct Output by same string using online JSON viewer.
[image: Correct Output by same string using online JSON viewer]

Comment: Double escape the quotes -- `\\"`. Once for the contents of the JSON string, again for the JavaScript string literal it's wrapped in.

Comment: reducing `\"` to `"` didn't work. Although `\"` to `\\"` works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use JSON viewer, it's different from when you use the code in your JS code. Like @Jonathan stated, you should double escape you json sting.

```js
JSON.parse('[["abc","{\\"icon\\":\\"adjust\\",\\"prefix\\":\\"fa\\",\\"markerColor\\":\\"red\\"}"],["xyz","{\\"icon\\":\\"archive\\",\\"prefix\\":\\"fa\\",\\"markerColor\\":\\"green\\"}"],["azs","{\\"icon\\":\\"asterisk\\",\\"prefix\\":\\"fa\\",\\"markerColor\\":\\"darkred\\"}"]]');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your json structure is invalid. You should use this instead(without slashes):

```
  '[["abc",["icon":"adjust","prefix":"fa","markerColor":"red"]],["xyz",["icon":"archive","prefix":"fa","markerColor":"green"]],["azs",["icon":"asterisk","prefix":"fa","markerColor":"darkred"]]'
```

Comment: there is a JSON String inside the provided JSON.
e.g: `"{\"icon\":\"adjust\",\"prefix\":\"fa\",\"markerColor\":\"red\"}"` You can treat the above JSON as Key pair value. 
`["abc","{\"icon\":\"adjust\",\"prefix\":\"fa\",\"markerColor\":\"red\"}"]` here `abc` is key and `"{\"icon\":\"adjust\",\"prefix\":\"fa\",\"markerColor\":\"red\"}"` is value

Comment: It's not necessarily invalid, just uncommon. Some of the string values within the JSON just themselves contain more JSON: `JSON.stringify([ 'abc', JSON.stringify({ icon: 'adjust' }) ])`

Comment: replacing `\"` to `\\"` works for me. By the way, the above string works correctly [Here](https://www.jsoneditoronline.org/)